# Hacer focus en componente Java

Tags: java, java-swing

en mi aplicación necesito hacer foco en un jTextField y no sabría como.
Ya intente con requestFocus() dentro del constructor de la clase y no le hace foco.

```
public jugar() {
    initComponents();

    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setTitle("Bienvenido " + menu.nombre);
    txt_letra.setVisible(false);
    button_validar.setVisible(false);
    jPanel1.setBackground(new Color(130, 0, 0));
    jPanel2.setBackground(new Color(130, 0, 0));
    jTextField.requestFocus();


}
```

Comment: intenta con requestFocusInWindow(), ademas de esto el componente donde se cuentre el TextField ya debe poseer el foco(si no mal recuerdo...) por tanto puede que sea necesario la llamada recursiva. panel.requestFocusInWindow(); jTextField.requestFocusInWindow();

Comment: otra opcion es grabFocus(), recomiendo la lectura de esta respuesta en ingles: [Difference between requestFocusInWindow() and grabFocus() in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680817/difference-between-requestfocusinwindow-and-grabfocus-in-swing)

Comment: Muchas gracias, use grabFocus() me sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca

```
jTextField.grabFocus()
```

Ya que `requestFocus` no lo hace al instance.

Comment: Hay que leer la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#grabFocus())... Traducción rápida: _El código cliente no debe utilizar este método; **en su lugar, debe utilizar `requestFocusInWindow()`**._ Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.